Python. How to define a Union type where one of the options is bool, but this bool can only take the value False
I have a function myfunction that returns a rather complicated custom type MyClass, or False when the result does not exist, or is irrelevant. Returning False is simpler and I assume more efficient that constructing an instance of MyClass that evaluates to False.  Code using the myfunction checks whether the return value is True, not False, before processing the returned object.  This works fine.
I now add type hints and run into a problem.  I can define:
def myfunction(zap: SomeType) -> MyClass|bool.

This also works fine. The problem is when calling myfunction. For example.
value = myfunction(dadada)
if not value:
    return None  # We return None when myfunction has nothing useful to return
if value.someattribute > 1:
   ...

The type checker complains that someattribute may not exist. This is correct, it does not exist when the return value of myfunction is bool. However, if the return is bool, it is False, and this is filtered out. The type checker might be smart enough to see this if it would know the bool can only take the value False, but it does not know that.
I tried, without hope, the following, but it of course does not work:
def myfunction(dadada) -> MyClass|False.

How can I solve this problem, without changing the code to always return a complex MyClass instance?

typing.Literal[False]

This sounds like you should return None instead of False.

Brilliant. I quickly (and superficially) tested this, and it seems to work. At least, the type checker does not complain on the someattribute. A simple and limpid solution.
Thanks. This is much appreciated.

This question is similar to: May I use True for Python type hintings?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Both solve the problem in a simple and limpid manner. The first has the benefit I do not have to change the body of the function, only the type declaration.  The second may be clearer in may situations, but not in my case.
Thanks. This is much appreciated.

There are a couple of issues here: not value doesn't trigger type narrowing, because not value doesn't imply anything about the type of value. Further, type narrowing only applies to the body of the if statement, not the code following the if statement.

Returning None and using the check if value is None: ... would solve the first issue, but not the second.

"Returning False is [...] more efficient that constructing an instance of MyClass that evaluates to False." That's an assumption you should test. Even if it is less efficient, is it less efficient enough to matter?

test using isinstance(value,MyClass) ... else# : # its boolean ...

@chepner.  Indeed, that returning False was just a (reasonable) assumption.  However, I am adding type checking on existing code, as documentation mainly. The code works fine, and I do not want to change this.

@chepner. About not triggering type narrowing. Actually, now that I use Literal[False] type checking works fine. It no longer complains about value.someattribute outside the if statement, whereas with bool it did. It seems to be smart enough to figure out what is going on.
